# How to set maven pom in order to adding specific file in installed jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i never used maven before, so i need help.

My question is how i have to set the pom in order to include specific files?

I mean, when i launch mvn install the generated jar contains all classes but those specific files are ignored, indeed when i use maven-jar-plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>${basedir}/**/*.mtl</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the installed jar contains only the META_INF folder.

Obviously, i cannot move those file under the resources folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put them into `src/main/resources` directory. Why can't you put them there? They should be packaged into the jar so they belong there...

Comment: "but those specific files are ignored, indeed when i use maven-jar-plugin": which specific files and where are they located? Unless you post them, we cannot know what you're doing and difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i cannot move those file from their specific folder. I'm using acceleo in a standalone configuration, and it automatically generates a java class for each .mtl files.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify additional resource directories with the Maven Resources Plugin

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Comment: Thanks, I have already found it, and whether I set resources to be included in the jar, I will obtain only those files.